# msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail does not execute within a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, service-broker

I've used the following code to set up deadlock monitoring:

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/07/18/Immediate-deadlock-notifications-without-changing-existing-code.aspx

and it works fine.
The problem I have is that msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail doesn't seem to work.
If I manually execute from my session, **It works fine**, but from within the stored procedure, the following error occurs:

2011-08-23 16:42:45.28 spid219s    The activated proc [dbo].[usp_ProcessNotification] running on queue Wayne.dbo.DeadLockNotificationsQueue output the following:  'Error WHILE receiving Service Broker message FROM queue DeadLockNotificationsQueue.
                        DATABASE Name: Wayne; Error number: 229; Error Message: The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_send_dbmail', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.'

I also ran the following:

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'DatabaseMailUserRole'
    ,@membername = '';

with my logon as the membername but it didn't seem to help.

What do I need to do to rectify this?

Thanks.

Wayne.

Comment: It is to do with the account that the activation procedure is running under. That needs to be in the correct role. See this article http://rusanu.com/2006/01/12/why-does-feature-not-work-under-activation/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Martin pointed to the right cause, the EXECUTE AS context under which your activated procedure runs. You can use code signing to grant the required permissions, as shown in [Call a procedure in another database from an activated procedure](http://rusanu.com/2006/03/07/call-a-procedure-in-another-database-from-an-activated-procedure/). Or you can simply mark the database `Wayne` [trustworthy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187861.aspx):

```
ALTER DATABASE [Wayne] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;
```

The former method is complicated, but is a must in a secure environment. The later method is much easier, but it implies that the dbo of `Wayne` database can escalate himself to sysadmin privileges. If the security issue is not a concern, you can use the simpler TRUSTWORTHY approach.,

Comment: Use the option that doesn't require trustworthy.  The trustworthy option is like saying "I trust all current *and future* code in this database".  Not a good place to be.  Besides, the procedure for signing the sproc and all that is not *that* complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a procedure in msdb that calls sp_send_dbmail, then grant execute to public on the calling procedure, as suggested by gbn: [How to execute sp_send_dbmail while limiting permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530320/how-to-execute-sp-send-dbmail-while-limiting-permissions).  It is not required to add users to msdb to run the procedure.  Obviously, this allows anyone to send mail, subject to procedural logic.